# disable USB autosuspend in Ubuntu Studio 19.04

Tags: usb, ubuntu-studio

I am looking for a way to disable USB auto-suspend on a Ubuntu Studio 19.04.
I have searched the web but could not find anything conclusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install [TLP](http://linrunner.de/tlp):

```
$ sudo apt install tlp
```

Then configure it to disable USB autosuspend by edit:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/default/tlp
```

You can find related setting - "USB_AUTOSUSPEND", after set it to 0, restart TLP by:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart tlp
```

Alternatively, you can try [another way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91027/how-to-disable-usb-autosuspend-on-kernel-3-7-10-or-above), which don't need to install anything